# SonarQube Version - 5.6.6 shows Still waiting for WebServer

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I have problem with SonarQube-5.6.6 Server Service Startup

Our Environment details as follows:

```
SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit)
Operating System – Ubuntu - 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**Problem Description:**

I have copied the dumped mysql file from another sonarqube-5.1 version server and I have successfully restored in my current sonarqube-5.6.6 server.

Later when I tried to start the SonarQube service, It shows below details,

```
2017.05.23 14:46:36 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2017.05.23 14:46:36 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp/sq-process2919432455637110534properties
2017.05.23 14:46:37 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2017.05.23 14:46:37 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Waiting for Web Server to be operational...
2017.05.23 14:46:38 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:46:40 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:46:45 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:46:58 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:47:32 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:49:06 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2017.05.23 14:53:21 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
```

So could you help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Verify that you followed the [SonarQube Upgrade Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading), make sure to follow each of the steps there, and update your question with related findings and full logs (not just an excerpt).

Comment: You could also change the [loglevel](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Server+Log+Management)

Comment: Hi Team,


Issue fixed by dropping the MYSQL Database and created newly & restored again then followed the upgrade procedure, it worked perfectly.


Thank you so much for the support.


-Mohan

Comment: I fixed this with simply navigating to "<sonarserver>/setup" and upgrading the database :)